# How threadsafe is an EventListenerList?

Tags: java, multithreading, events, event-handling

The [Javadoc for EventListenerLists](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html) says that they offer "a degree of MT safety (when used correctly)."  What does that mean? I see that making the copy of the array protects you from having things removing themselves as you're firing, so under what circumstances will this fail?

More specifically, I'm trying to build an EventBus to simplify some increasingly complicated event-passing in a multi-threaded application. I'm afraid of what might happen if multiple threads are trying to fire/react to events, I'm also afraid of enforcing safety with blocking mechanisms because the point of my threads is to keep my UI from blocking on expensive tasks.

Comment: Actually in my opinion it's not thread safe with regard to CPU access rearranges. Probably it will never be observed on x86, though.

Comment: @bestsss: It's not just your opinion, it's a fact. :-) Seriously, not having the `volatile` was very sloppy. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not very thread-safe. :-( (Based on the [OpenJDK 6 version](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/506b35a2f558/src/share/classes/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.java) of the code.)

Things they did right:

1. The `add` and `remove` methods are marked `synchronized`, so a call to one won't happen at the same time as a call to the other
2. The listener list arrays are never modified; `add` and `remove` always assign a new array to `listenerList`

Things they did wrong (unfortunately):

1. The `listenerList` field is not `volatile`
2. The `getListenerList()` method is not `synchronized`

That means, if you call `add` or `remove` in one thread, and then call `getListenerList` in another thread, the changes may not be observed, and you may still get back the old version of the listener list.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for better alternatives? I was thinking of using a ConcurrentSkipListSet, but I'm not sure that would deal with your two points about things done wrong, or that it would keep your two points about things done right.

Comment: actually, I think I can live with that kind of failure, it won't seriously affect my program if an event or two get lost while adding, or a couple leak through while removing. Thanks.

Comment: @Dogmatixed: Well, if one day you decide you can't deal with that, `CopyOnWriteArraySet` is perfect for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Chris, while volatile is needed it's "swing" stuff, so the listenerList field will be visible at some point (I disregard an option the field to stay forever cached into a CPU register). So it will be eventually consistent. However it is not true that it's guaranteed that: *But, at least you will never observe a partially-modified listener list.* Unless the JVM uses intrinsics for the listenerList  field. Reader thread CAN see partially 'added' listener, the CPU can rearrange `tmp[i] = t; tmp[i+1] = l; listenerList = tmp;` sequence. So it is NOT thread safe.

Comment: @bestsss: Yes, you're totally right. I forgot about the reordering (and I should not have forgotten). I'll revert my answer back to the first revision. ;-)

Comment: It looks like listenerList is volatile now. I don't know how that changes the thread safety.